# Prove that the limit of this sequence is $\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$

Tags: limits

I have the following exercise: Let $S_1$ = 1  and for $n \geq 1$  let $S_{n+1} = \sqrt{S_n + 1}$. Prove that the limit of this sequence is $\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$

Comment: First, it needs to show that the sequence converges? If it not necessary, then just "replace" $S_{n+1}$ and $S_n$ by $S$, where $S$ is the limit.

Comment: Step 1: The limit **exists**. By induction you can prove the sequence is increasing and bounded above. Step 2: A calculation.

Answer (score 4):

To be rigorous: first check that $S_2>S_1$ and $S_1<S_0\equiv\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$ and use an induction argument to show that $S_n$ is increasing and each $S_n$ is bounded above by $S_0$. Thus, a limit $S$ exists satisfying $S=\sqrt{S+1}$. You can then check that $S=S_0$.

---

**More details**: to check $S_1<S_2$, you simply plug in the numbers. Similarly, do the same for $S_1<S_0$.  Now, in one induction argument, you can verify both that $S_n$ is increasing and $S_n$ is bounded above by $S_0$. We have just done the base cases. The induction steps are
$$
S_{n+1}-S_n=\sqrt{S_n+1}-\sqrt{S_{n-1}+1}\geq 0\text{ if }S_n\geq S_{n-1};\\
S_{n+1}=\sqrt{S_n+1}\leq\sqrt{S_0+1}=S_0\text{ if }S_n\leq S_0.
$$
Therefore, now you have $\{S_n\}$ is an increasing sequence that is bounded above. So it has some limit $S$. This $S$ satisfies $S=\sqrt{S+1}$ which you obtain by taking the limits on both sides of $S_{n+1}=\sqrt{S_n+1}$. Note that this taking limits step isn't proper unless you first justify that the limit exists. Hence, the induction argument we did in the beginning.

Comment: can you explain a little more?

Comment: @ Pasie15: see edit.

Comment: So do we Assume $S_0 = \sqrt{5}$ ?

Comment: so the quadratic formula is the next step right?

Comment: @ Pasie15: I defined $S_0$ in the answer. Yes, you find $S$ using the quadratic formula. Remember that $S$ is the positive root among the two .

Comment: thank you very much man I figured it out

Comment: You don't need to use induction. You're proving that $S_{n+1} > S_n\,\forall n$ which doesn't need induction

Answer (score 1):

$$
S_{n+1}^2 = S_n + 1
$$
if a limit does exist then it occurs when 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{S_{n+1}}{S_n}=1
$$
i.e.
$$
M^2 = M + 1
$$

Comment: @5space cheers, I have to cover the possibility that a simple glance at the initial problem didn't converge. :). Though the other great answers have done that now :).

Answer (score 0):

The limit $L$ must satisfy
$$L=\sqrt{L+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** prove that $S_n$ is bounded and increasing after some $n$. Then, get $S_{n+1} = \sqrt{S_n + 1}$, and pass the limit to obtain $L = \sqrt{L+1}$. Then solve for $L$ (and discard the negative value you will find).

Comment: Crescent? Not a usual mathematical term in English. Did you mean 'increasing?'

Comment: English is not my native language, so sometimes I might not use the quite right terms. Thanks, that's what I meant (: